# Changing the text of a UILabel makes it reappear when using UIViewKeyframeAnimations

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewanimation

I have a series of animations I want to perform on `UILabel` so I looked up `UIViewKeyframeAnimations` added in iOS7.

A simplified version of what i want to do is:

1. Fade out UILabel with duration 0.5 seconds
2. Wait 1 second
3. Fade in UILabel with new text with duration 0.5 seconds

   ```
   NSTimeInterval duration = 2;
   [UIView animateKeyframesWithDuration:duration delay:0 options:UIViewKeyframeAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction | UIViewAnimationOptionOverrideInheritedOptions animations:^{
       [UIView addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime:0 relativeDuration:0.5/duration animations:^{
           self.label.alpha = 0;
       }];

       [UIView addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime:1.5/duration relativeDuration:0.5/duration animations:^{
           self.label.text = [@(arc4random_uniform(4000)) stringValue];
           self.label.alpha = 1;
       }];
   } completion:nil];
   ```

The result is that the label text is faded out and the reappears with new text, then faded out again and faded in again.

A video of the result: [Animation Failure](https://www.dropbox.com/s/h2t1yf1ife9oe4t/UIViewKeyframeAnimations.mov?dl=0)

Cheers
Morten

Answer (score 1):

You state: *"The result is that the label text is faded out and the reappears with new text, then faded out again and faded in again."*. What I see in the movie however, is that the alpha transition just works as expected, fade out and fade in. The only exception to your desired behaviour is that the text change is already applied as soon as the animation starts, rather than at the beginning of the second keyframe of your animation.

It's important to understand that the code inside the addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime blocks gets executed as soon as the animateKeyframesWithDuration gets called. Any animatable change (frame, alpha, etc) will be animated. Likewise, anything that is not an automatically animated view property (such as the label's text change) will be visible instantly.

To help illustrate this, try putting an NSLog statement at the beginning of all animation blocks (of both animateKeyframesWithDuration and addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime), and one in the completion block. You will see that each NSLog *except* for the one in the completion block has exactly the same log time.

For this exact reason, the code below *will* work, since the execution of the complete block is postponed until the first animation has finished:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1 animations:^{
    self.label.alpha = 0;
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    self.label.text = [@(arc4random_uniform(4000)) stringValue];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1 animations:^{
        self.label.alpha = 1;
    }];
}];
```

Comment: Ah okay, so my choices are 1. revert to the old animateWithDuration 2. Introduce a temporary `UILabel` and `UIImageView` 3. Use some 3rd party Promises framework. Option 1 gets really messy with long animations.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I would do: instead of using keyframes for a simple animation like this, i would use animations with block:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 animations:^
 {
     [self.label setAlpha:0.0];
     [self.imageview setAlpha:0.0];
 }
                 completion: ^(BOOL completed)
 {

     [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 delay:0.5 options:UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction animations:^
      {
          self.label.text = [@(arc4random_uniform(4000)) stringValue];
          [self.label setAlpha:1.0];
      }
                      completion: ^(BOOL completed)
      {

      }
      ];
     [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 delay:0.5 options:UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction animations:^
      {
          [self.imageview setAlpha:1.0];
          [self.imageview setFrame:frame];
      }
                      completion: ^(BOOL completed)
      {
          //if you need to do stuff after the animations finish, here you can do them.
      }
      ];
 }
 ];
```

Comment: Its a simplified version, the real scenario is:
Fade out a `UILabel` and a `UIImageView` with 0.25
Wait 0.5
Fade in `UILabel` with new text with 0.25
At the same time fade in and transform `UIImageView` with 1.0

Comment: You can use similar logic to construct your goal. The tricky part will be with the `UIImageView` imo. Give me a couple of minutes to code and try..

Comment: Yes it is possible but the nesting makes it harder to read and verify.

Comment: Try and see if it works, i didn't compile. And its just one level of nesting. Not more than the previous code.